# How to extract query string from a URL of a web-page using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, url, web, query-string

From the following URL in OathCallBack page I want extract access_token and token_type using Java. Any idea how to do it?

http://myserver.com/OathCallBack#state=/profile&access_token=ya29.AHES6ZQLqtYrPKuw2pMzURJtWuvINspm8-Vf5x-MZ5YzqVy5&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600

I tried the following, but unable to extract required information.

```
{
    String scheme = req.getScheme();             // http
    String serverName = req.getServerName();     // myserver.com
    int serverPort = req.getServerPort();        // 80
    String contextPath = req.getContextPath();   
    String servletPath = req.getServletPath();   
    String pathInfo = req.getPathInfo();         // return null and exception
    String queryString = req.getQueryString();    // return null

}
```

<---------------------------------------------------------->
I am going to edit my question

Thank you every one for nice reply,

google did it,

you can refer to that link by URL

http://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

inside above URL page there is following link

http://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth? scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww‌​.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile& state=%2Fprofile& redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth2-login-demo.appspot.com%2Foauthcallback& response_type=token& client_id=812741506391.apps.googleusercontent.com

when you click on above link, then you will get your gmail login account access_token, and that token is after # sign

Comment: in URL at the place of "?" is "#" therefore query string IS not extracting, it will be extracted if I able to read/get whole URL in a string, how to read complete URL including everything e.g., access_token

Comment: Have you tried req.getRequestURL()

Comment: req.getRequestURL() retrieve only http://myserver.com/OathCallBack and nothing other it, but I am interested in other arguments e.g.,  access_token etc

Comment: I edited original question please refer to it

Answer (score 0):

Some characters cannot be part of a URL (for example, the space) and some other characters have a special meaning in a URL: for example, the character # can be used to further specify a subsection (or fragment) of a document; the character = is used to separate a name from a value.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string for more:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the '#' should be a '?'.

In a normal URL, the parameters are passed as key value pairs following a '?' and multiple parameters chained together using '&'. A URL might look as follows:

http: //someserver.com/somedir/somepage.html?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3.

Normally the Java servlet container would return everything after the '?' when calling getQueryString() but due to the absence of the '?' it returns null.

As @Sandeep Nair has suggested getRequestURL() should return this full URL to you and you could parse it using regular expressions to get the information you want. A possible regular expression to use would be along the lines of:

```
(?<=access_token=)[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*
```

However, getRequestURL() does NOT normally return the query string, so using this method is relying on the fact that there is a '#' rather and a '?' and is therefore probably not a great solution. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29).

I would advise that you find out why you are getting a '#' instead of a '?' and try to get this changed, if you can do this then the servlet container should manage the URL parameters for you and call to request.getAttribute("access_token") and request.getAttribute("token_type") (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)) will return both values as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You get query string by calling 
  String queryString = req.getQueryString();

It correctly returns null in your case, as there is no query string. The characters after "#" are anchor specification, which is only visible to the browser and not sent to server.